# Python 3 - sys.getsizeof() adding 17 bits to file

Tags: python-3.x, sys

```
import sys
import binascii

filename = ('terrain.png')
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
binascii.hexlify(content)
x = sys.getsizeof(content)
print (x)
```

Ok so this is the bit of code i started with, it prints '333983' when it should print '333966'.
its 17 more bytes than it should be and im not sure why. i checked the images size manually with hex workshop. i need to get this images exact byte size for a custom pack file im writing. the images file size is going to be listed in the header in hex form before the file structure. im pretty new to python, so sorry if i made some errors.

Comment: Sensitive? Don't make me laugh. (You do realize that previous versions of the question are plainly visible to anyone who cares?)

Comment: dont waste my time, of course i know that. but it wont be blatently in your face when you search "Death_Dealer". i dont need to explain myself to you. why dont you go be a troll elsewhere.

Comment: The answer of @DSM should be marked as correct. Also, I have resetted the previous version since the tl;dr of the author is nearly irrelevant for the question, but the code is crucial. I was searching for the same answer, which should even be clear just by looking at the question's code. If something should be removed, its the text, not the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.getsizeof` returns the size of the *Python object*, not the number of bytes in a bytestring, or the length of a string, or the length of a tuple, etc.  You're just measuring an implementation detail of the interpreter.  (`sys.getsizeof` isn't even implemented in PyPy, for example.)  This will vary depending on the type:

```
>>> a = [1]*100
>>> len(a)
100
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
432    
>>> b = b'1'*100
>>> len(b)
100
>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
117
```

If you want to know the number of bytes, since your `content` is a `bytes` object, you can simply use `len(content)`.

Comment: Ok yep that fixed it. im thinking sys.getsizeof() is for internal work. thank you for the response.